# Нужна ли запятая после слов "пройдя конкурс"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Пройдя конкурс, Вы повысите свои профессиональные навыки и сделаете шаг вверх по карьерной лестнице.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

Всё верно, запятая нужна. Деепричастный оборот в подобных случаях [выделяется запятыми](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113).

Answer (score 2):

**Пройдя конкурс** — это деепричастный оборот (деепричастие с зависимым словом), который, как правило, обособляется независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому.
[Обособление деепричастного оборота](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/)

В вашем предложении пунктуация правильная.
Посмотрите, оборот выделяется запятыми в любом месте.

***Пройдя конкурс,*** Шумилов заключил контракт сроком на 10 лет и был назначен на должность (С. Хазанов, Н. Новоселова. Административное право. Практикум).

*Дом, куда ей посчастливилось устроиться работать, **пройдя конкурс,** построен на две состоятельные семьи* (Л. Соболева. Смертельная цена успеха).

*В 15 лет, **пройдя конкурс,** стала солисткой Рижского оркестра радио и телевидения под руководством Раймонда Паулса* (из статьи о Л. Вайкуле).